# _ah/warmup keeps getting called

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine server up and running. I don't have any cron jobs or anything that I am aware that calls the default website url. I have had over 70,000 requests for the _ah/warmup in the last 24 hours. How can I figure where this traffic is coming from? Is this a denial of service attack on the server?

Comment: What response code is /_ah/warmup returning?

Comment: I get the same issue running `node` (express) on GAE.  It appears to be an infinite cycle of 302 / 307 redirects between https and http.  It appears independent of whether or not `secure: always` is enabled.  Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The warmup request is, as explained by the [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_Warmup_requests), an internal call that is made whenever you spin up new instances.

Without any more information, the only thing 70 000 requests to that URL means is that your scaling is maybe a bit too aggressive and your app is spinning too many instances.